# RTX 2060 6GB vs RTX 2060 12GB in near future

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, video-editing, nvidia

As you know RTX 2060 was relaunched with 12GB VRAM and other changes like more cuda cores but less bandwidth.

I checked performance of both on various benchmarking websites and they are more or less same for 1080p gaming. I'm interested in buying the 12GB version for following two personal conclusions:

1. 12GB is obviously a lot more than 6GB. Even if this card is basically similar as old one in terms of other specifications, it's still better than 6GB memory, by some percentage. For example, it might not be powerful enough for 12GB, but maybe its performance won't degrade upto 7GB or even 8GB.
2. It might perform better in non gaming tasks like video editing and basic 3D modelling, irrespective of similar specifications apart from VRAM.

---

Now the other thing is, when it was relaunched, it was criticized by almost everyone. Mainly for its price. *And many people say it isn't even powerful enough for 12GB so it's a scam*. I'm not sure how true is it especially the "powerful enough" thing.

I really don't think pricing is factor now because the pricing has become much better today, the only concern remains about the performance. Not sure if I am going to see any benefit of 12GB at present or near future.

I can't afford a display greater than 1080p in near future. And I have no plans either. **But I think that maybe in next 2-3 years games might need a little more than 6GB for 1080p gaming.** So I'm not sure if I should invest in 12GB or 6GB. The price different isn't that big.

Like I said, right now their performance benchmarks are more or less same. But if this 12GB makes the card a little more better as compared to 6GB variant in near future, *especially in gaming*, I would prefer the 12GB one.

**So which one do you recommend?**

Comment: The "powerful enough for 12GB" thing sounds like a bunch of hot air to me. It's just not logically sound to say "This graphics setting needs a faster GPU and it also uses more RAM, therefore a GPU that isn't fast enough for this feature won't need the extra RAM." There are lots of ways to fill up the VRAM and even the "slowest" GPUs can make use of all the VRAM they have.

Comment: regarding # [cuda] cores unless you know whatever software/game is maxing out on cores or coming close then that parameter is mostly not relevant.  What is relevant is 1080 vs 1440 (2k) and 2160 (4k), and are there 8k monitors now?  At 4k monitor resolution 6gb vram will not be enough for a *max video* setting in current high end games and will become more so in the future.  "1080p gaming" is even obsolete, the norm is 3840x2160.  The "relaunch" with 12gb should be the indicator telling you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely go with the 12GB variety, always err on the side of more VRAM rather than less. I was looking up Forza Horizon5 VRAM allocation, at 1080p extreme settings it uses almost 8GB as per KitGuru

Comment: Could you please share source/link of "KitGuru" where Forza 5 is discussed?

Comment: https://www.kitguru.net/components/graphic-cards/dominic-moass/forza-horizon-5-pc-performance-benchmark-30-gpus-tested/